# How do I start a previously stopped Azure Container instance using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-container-service

I have the following code to stop an Azure container instance and would like to start it using similar.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;

 var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal("XXXX",                "XXXX", "XXXX", AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithSubscription("XXXXX");

        var containerName = "mycontainer";
        var containerGroup = azure.ContainerGroups.GetByResourceGroup("myResourceGroup", containerName);
        if (containerGroup.State == "Running")
        {
            containerGroup.Stop();
        }
```

I would like to do the same and start my azure container instance. So where is containerGroup.Start(); ? This does not appear to exist in the interface. I have tried using containerGroup.Restart(); but this does not work from a stopped state. I need to be able to do this from within C# code and would like to avoid powershell if possible.

Comment: The new fluent SDK has not been updated with Start support, but it's on the way! The non-fluent flavor SDK has the start support though, if that works for you.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Comment: It does not answer my question. Thanks for your input

Comment: What answer do you expect? The C# function to start the container group in the stopped state?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this but it is not exposed in the fluent API:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent;

// azure is an instance of IAzure; the fluent Azure API
var resources = await azure.ContainerGroups.ListAsync();

foreach(var containerGroup in resources.Where(aci => aci.State != "Running"))
{
  await ContainerGroupsOperationsExtensions.StartAsync(
           containerGroup.Manager.Inner.ContainerGroups,
           containerGroup.ResourceGroupName, 
           containerGroup.Name);
}
```

As mentioned by other people, you do need to realize that this is effectively starting a fresh container. No state will be maintained from the previous run unless you persisted that somewhere else like in a [mounted volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files).

You'll also need to grant the appropriate rights to whom ever is executing this code. I'm using a function so I had to setup a service account and a role, this [blog post](https://matthewdavis111.com/powershell/azure-container-instance-teamcity/) has all the details.

**Update**
The code I'm using is in on GitHub: https://github.com/alanta/azure_scheduler/blob/master/src/StartACIs.cs

Comment: Hi, is there any way to change the env vars before starting the container group? The documentation seems a bit cryptic

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that from the management API but I can think of some alternative ways of passing data to the container group. You should probably post a new question if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: thanks, posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406374/azure-container-instances-net-sdk-change-environment-variable-and-restart-t

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when you stop the container instances, they would be in the Terminated state and you cannot start them again.

> Terminated or deleted container groups can't be updated. Once a
>   container group has stopped (is in the Terminated state) or has been
>   deleted, the group is deployed as new.

Even if you update the ACI, it also means the ACI would be redeployed. You can take a look at [Update containers in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update). In addition, the Restart action also works when the container instances are in the running state.

So there is no start function in the C# SDK for you, at least now. Hope this will help you.

**Update**

Take a look at the event:

[image]

Each time when you start the container group after stop, the container group always these steps: pull the image -> create the container group -> start the container instances. So it’s clear, the container group was recreated when you start it after stop.

Comment: If this were true, why can I start them from the portal? If you see the comment above @Anders indicates it will be added to the fluent SDK and already exists in the non-fluent SDK. It also exists in powershell

Comment: @johnstaveley I show the test screenshot in the answer. Hope it will help you.